# Unnecessary unboxing in java - how to refactor the code?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, boxing

I have the following Java 8 code (simplified for demonstration):

```
public Double fooBar(int a) {
    return Double.valueOf(a);
}
```

Now IntelliJ IDEA tells me that I have unnecessary boxing in the return statement. I'd understand this problem if `a` were a `double` type, but for an `int` I feel that I need the boxing to have the conversion to `double`.

Is there a good way to refactor this code which I currently don't see or is the error message from IntelliJ IDEA at this point simply not optimal?

Thanks for help

Comment: surely an `int` value can be contained in a `double`

Comment: @ScaryWombat: I don't understand your comment. You mean I could remove the explicit boxing statement? To my understanding I can't.

Comment: simply return `a`

Comment: The code does not containt any unnecessary boxing. We should see calling code.

Comment: @MathiasBader If you have a double variable you can assign any integer value to it, no need for a conversion method.

Comment: The method gets a primitive and returns an object, I don't think is it possible *not* to box in this case. Can you return a double instead of Double?

Comment: The code doesn't work as is, the convertion `int` > `Double` is not possible. What is possible (and my prefered solution by @vikingsteve) is casting from `int` to `double` and let Java do the implicit boxing to `Double`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use alt-enter to use the suggested resolution"Remove boxing", the result is this:

```
public Double fooBar(int a) {
    return (double) a;
}
```

In this case the conversion from `int` to `double` is very explicit, whilst at the same time avoiding manual boxing.

Comment: I like that one. How did you do this Alt-Enter trick? For me this message is only a tool-tip-text and I can expand it pressing Ctrl + F1 ...

Comment: You need to have the cursor located at the error - hit f2 until it is located on the relevant code, then alt-enter should work

Comment: @ScaryWombat if you just have `return a;` (no cast) there is an error "Incompatible types" (Double vs int).

Comment: The compiler will still box it for you, since a Double object must be created

Comment: FWIW, i just hacked in both variants of FooBar and disassembled the code - as i suspected, they are both translated to the very same bytecode:

    // Variant a
    public Double foo(int x) {
        return Double.valueOf(x);
    }
    
    public Double bar(int x) {
        return (double)x;
    }
 
  public java.lang.Double foo(int);
    Code:
       0: iload_1
       1: i2d
       2: invokestatic  #2
       5: areturn

  public java.lang.Double bar(int);
    Code:
       0: iload_1
       1: i2d
       2: invokestatic  #2
       5: areturn

Comment: @ScaryWombat `return a;` => *Incompatible types. Required: java.lang.Double Found: int*. Note that this is an IntelliJ error / inspection. The compiler might say something else.

Comment: @GyroGearless fantastic. nice analysis. The issue then is really one about readability (which is more clear?) and usability (is it nice to have the inspection "pass" in IntelliJ, or should one just disable the inspection?)

Comment: @vikingsteve - i think the point for this particular case is, that one is urged to refactor some perfectly valid code to make IntelliJ happy. Would consider this as a bug in IntelliJ's code inspector..

Comment: Wouldn't say it's a bug, but perhaps superfluous. In any case `int` -> `Double` type conversion needs to be handled somehow, unless the return type can be changed to `double` (see urval's answer).

Comment: Thanks for the trick with F2 and Alt-Enter. That works perfectly - I just additionally learned something incredibly useful :-D

Answer (score 7):

How about staying in the primitive realm the whole way through?

```
public double fooBar(int a) {
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Can we presume changing return type from `Double` to `double` won't break anything?

Comment: @vikingsteve How can it break anything? You can always assign the return value to a Double, and it will auto-box at that assignment. Or keep the return value as a double, which is much more efficient

Comment: It's not possible to change the method return type here. By the way: That might actually break a lot of things - auto-boxing is not that simple and does definitely not always 'just work'.

Comment: @MathiasBader Do you mind sharing an example what can break if replacing Double with double? (The only case I'm aware of that it might get in the way is if you're expecting an Object for some polymorphism, but it seem unrelated to your question)

Comment: @uval: With greatest pleasure. (1) null-pointer: If you replace return value `Double` with `double`, there might sometimes be a `null` returned where you are not aware. Those break, because unboxing is not possible. (2) Some methods are overloaded with only difference `Double` in the first and `double` in the second overloaded method. Even though it's bad practice, you never know. I just got this example three weeks ago at work, where I thought I could easily refactor without breaking things. (3) many more ...

Comment: @uval: Don't want to go into detail in a comment here, but as often, details are key and simply refactoring and thinking everything will work for sure is definitely not the case. The bigger the project, the surer I would bet, that it will break some code. Search the web for more examples.

Comment: @uval: My favourite example where you can't just remove boxing/unboxing (from plain java): If you have `List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>()` and you add number 3, 2 and 1 and then call `a.remove(1)`, it will actually delete position one which is 2. If you call `a.remove(Integer.valueOf(1))` it will remove the element 1. IntelliJ IDEA actually knows this and will not suggest a correction here :-D

Comment: Nice example. The ambiguity of remove from a list is indeed a case not to mix object with a primitive. But the other examples are not as convincing. (2) @Override would not let you change Double to double. (1) a primitive can never be null.
I agree that in large systems (like yours) using Double is safer, but in restricted systems (such as Android - my domain), where memory and performance are  limited (and not using this for a List), this is a valid optimization.

Comment: I totally agree that `double` makes a lot of sense (I personally prefer the unboxed types myself). My point was that just changing code in big systems can break things were you wouldn't expect it. Changing a `Double` to a `double` can indeed lead to `null`, for example if it is the return type of a method and somewhere `null` is returned. In these cases, the existing code will not work anymore.

Comment: For point (2): I'm not talking about Overwritte, but more of when you for example call a method with a primitive instead of a boxed one.
But as the discussion shows: This topic is tricky ;-)

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be to not refactor the code.
The original code is fine and optimal, we don't need anything happening under the covers.
Autoboxing is unnecessary IMHO.